# Multipart formdata not working with Jersey and JaxRs

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I want to build support for fileupload using Jersey (2.22.2) & JaxRs.

This is my application:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class DsmJaxRsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

        classes.add(FileUploadResource.class);
        classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);

        return classes;
    }
}
```

This is my resource method to intercept the POST request:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("upload")
public Response uploadImportFile(@FormDataParam("reason") String reason,
                                 @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName,
                                 @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileContent) {
    checkCreateBulkChangeAllowed();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

And this is my request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAh9J98cKgsOv6WCr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reason"

wwwww
------WebKitFormBoundaryAh9J98cKgsOv6WCr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

DSM_CH_Bulk_new.xlsx
------WebKitFormBoundaryAh9J98cKgsOv6WCr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="DSM_CH_Bulk_new.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


------WebKitFormBoundaryAh9J98cKgsOv6WCr--
```

The problem is that inside the method both the `fileContent` and the `reason` contain "wwww" which should be the reason and the `fileName` is always `null`. Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My configuration was based in a web.xml file. Try to add 
*FormDataContentDisposition*

```
@POST
@Path("upload/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadInspectionFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition content,
        @FormDataParam("path") String path)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my servlet in my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet_inspector</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,com.sagasoftware.service;com.sagasoftware.custom.filter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature ,
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers,
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and here are my dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<version>1</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Tried with `FormDataContentDisposition` and that object is also null, can you provide me the web.xml config, maybe I can figure it out from there.

Comment: @Marius I updated my answer. Also i have seen people using final FormDataMultiPart entity. your resource method should be like this: public Response uploadImportFile(final FormDataMultiPart entity){ .... }