# Message body reader not found for multipart/form-data - Un Supported media type(415) Error

Tags: jersey

Below is the signature of my webservice method that accepts attachment with it's `content-type = multipart/form-data`

```
@POST  @Path("/saveimg")    
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response saveAttachment( @FormDataParam("files") InputStream fileInputStream,
             @FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
```

I got the following error:

> SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class
> com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and Java type
> class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and MIME
> media type multipart/form-data;
> boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryiNkfu0uRssIuZMPX was not found.
> The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
> */* ->
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider

Comment: When I changed the consumer content-type to @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  the above error log disappears but server 415 ( Un Supported Media Type) persists.                                          The request sent has content-type multipart/form-data including boundary along with mulitipart/form-data.

Comment: Check my answer in a previous post, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361880/multipart-formdata-not-working-with-jersey-and-jaxrs/38362314#38362314

Comment: For some reason, I'm not using Maven. Can you tell me what is missing?

Comment: it seems you need to have the jar for multipart. Are you using glassfish libraries?

Comment: check this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart

Comment: I'm using Tomcat. I added jersey-multipart-1.19.1.jar, jersey-media-multipart-2.0 and mimepull-1.6.

Comment: I know you are not using a maven project but in my old answer I added a part of my web.xml. Did you see it?. Also check this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/

Comment: You're still using Maven. I'm not using maven now. I know I can convert it but I temporarily not using maven. I understand I've to shift. For now, better is to cite the jars missing, the root cause of the error. I don't see any wrong on the code. The conflict of jars is messing me up as far as my knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to remove FormDataContentDisposition, I removed it and now I don't have 415 error... but I have to find an other way to get the information needed.

my file here:@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileStream.

I tried to read file like that:

final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
    String text = CharStreams.toString(reader);

but not my final solution... i'm looking for other solution... 
hope I could be helpfully.

Comment: Please format the code part of the question.Please go through how to post the question on Stack overflow once so it will be easy for others to go through the problem you are facing

Comment: FormDataContentDisposition is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

However late answered, I solved my problem by using Jersey 2 Framework. Jersey version 1 didn't work for me. Apart from that, the required libraries are:

```
    jersey-media-multipart-2.25

    mimepull-1.9.7
```

Note: I used jackson provider - jersey-media-json-jackson-2.5.1

Easily, it's possible to test it from Chrome POSTMAN

```
   >> method - PUT, POST
   >> Give Path(URL) of your resource method
   >> Body -- form-data  
   >> key -- should match with @@FormDataParam argument
   >> Choose File -> browse but make sure it's **File** type not Text
   >> Yeah, Hit SEND
```